# Every time an object is appended to JSON. a new top value is created

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind

When I try to take user input and add the list to the JSON file, it adds a new array and an all array that isn't defined anywhere. I have it appending and if I don't, it removes any previous information in JSON. I've seen JSONObject being used, but JSONObject isn't available just JSONPObject.

I've tried various ways of writing the user input to JSON and none of them change anything.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<Car> jsonList;
    jsonList = mapper.readValue(new File("cars.json"),
            new TypeReference<List<Car>>(){});
try{
    String make;
    String model;
    int year;
    String color;
    int miles;

    System.out.println("Input information you want to add");

    System.out.println("Input make");
    make = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Input model");
    model = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Input year");
    String userI2 = scan.nextLine();
    year = Integer.parseInt(userI2);

    System.out.println("Input color");
    color = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Input miles");
    userI2 = scan.nextLine();
    miles = Integer.parseInt(userI2);

    Car cars = new Car();
    cars.setmake(make);
    cars.setmodel(model);
    cars.setcolor(color);
    cars.setmiles(miles);
    cars.setyear(year);

    carList.add(cars);

    String jsonCarList = mapper.writeValueAsString(carList);

    System.out.println(jsonCarList);

    writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("cars.json", true));

    writer.println(jsonCarList);
}catch (FileNotFoundException | JsonProcessingException e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());

}catch (IOException e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}finally {
    if (writer != null) {
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
```

Car code:

```
private String make;
    private String model;
    private int year;
    private String color;
    private int miles;

    public Car(String make, String model, int year, String color, int miles) {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.year = year;
        this.color = color;
        this.miles = miles;
    }

private List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();

    public Car() {

    }

    public void add(Car newCar){

        carList.add(newCar);
    }

    public String getmake() {
        return make;
    }

    public void setmake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }

    public String getmodel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setmodel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public int getyear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setyear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getcolor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setcolor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getmiles() {
        return miles;
    }

    public void setmiles(int miles) {
        this.miles = miles;
    }
```

This creates a JSON file that looks like this:

```json
[{"make":"toyota","model":"camry","year":2011,"color":"gray","miles":90000,"all":[]}]
[{"make":"nissan","model":"rogue","year":1093,"color":"red","miles":49040,"all":[]}]
```

instead of

```json
[{"make":"toyota","model":"camry","year":2011,"color":"gray","miles":90000},
{"make":"nissan","model":"rogue","year":1093,"color":"red","miles":49040}]
```

Comment: What does the javadoc say about the second argument you pass to the FileWriter constructor? And what is the code of `Car`?

Comment: Post the exact and complete code of the class in your question.

Comment: Okay updated with the Car code.

Comment: That's not the exact and complete code. If you posted your exact and complete code, we could reproduce the issue, by just running it. Since you don't, we're forced to guess what you're hiding. Also, why don't you respect the Java naming convention? The getter and settef for a property foo should be named `getFoo()` and setFoo()`. Your IDE can generate them for you.

Comment: And also, you still haven't answered my question: What does the javadoc say about the second argument you pass to the FileWriter constructor?

Comment: Where do you define/initalize `carList` in the car class?

Comment: Are you talking about the true after the file name? If so, that's telling it to append instead of replace.

Also I do have the getters and setters generated for me.

Comment: You have a method `public void add(Car newCar){

        carList.add(newCar);
    }` but `carList` isn't in the car class.

Comment: @AnnaNichols no decent IDE would ever generate such getters and setters. And why do you pass true, since you want to replace the old JSON list by the new JSON list?

Comment: I don't want to replace the old JSON list. I want what is entered by the user to be added to the JSON list which is where the issue comes in. If I already have [{make: jeep, model: wrangler, year: 2019, color: red, miles: 3234}] in the JSON and add a new one it becomes [{make: jeep, model: wrangler, year: 2019, color: red, miles: 3234}] [{make: nissan, model: rogue, year: 2017, color: red, miles: 32334}]

Intellij did. I don't see what's wrong with the getters and setters. Model for example because getModel() which is how you said it should be.

Comment: Please take some time to think about what you said, and what your code does. What do you write to the file?

Comment: Also take some time to think about the design of your Car class. In the real life, does a car have a list of cars? If it doesn't in real life, why does you Car class have a list of cars?

Comment: Because it's basically a car inventory instead of one individual car. It's suppose add user input to the object that already exists in the JSON file so it becomes instead of [{make: jeep, model: wrangler, year: 2019, color: red, miles: 3234},{make: nissan, model: rogue, year: 2017, color: red, miles: 32334}].

Comment: So, the class CarInventory could have a list of cars. But each car shouldn't have a list of cars. I'm trying to help. Why you have `all` in your JSON is probably because in your Car class, maybe the first time you wrote in the file, you had a field named `all`, that you probably renamed `carList` now. If you thing there shouldn't be an empty array in the JSON, then you should also think that a Car shouldn't have an empty list of cars. And if you're wondering why you have several arrays in your file, it's because every time you execute your code, you **append** a new list of cars to the file.

Comment: I haven't written getters and setters in a while. Or had the IDE generate them, either. If you use Lombok you can just annotate the class with `@Data`. It's much, much easier. Also, a car should never, ever contain a list of cars. You can't put a bunch of cars in the trunk of your car. That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with the model itself. The Car itself holding a list of Car doesn't make any sense. The better way is to write another class CarInventory which holds a list of Car objects and remove the "carList" from the Car class

```
public class CarInventory {

    private List<Car> carList;

    public List<Car> getCarList() {
        if(carList == null)
            carList = new ArrayList<>();
        return carList;
    }

    public void setCarList(List<Car> carList) {
        this.carList = carList;
    }

    public void addCar(Car car) {
        getCarList().add(car);
    }
}
```

Then in your main modify the read to

```
CarInventory inventory = mapper.readValue(new File("cars.json"),
                    CarInventory.class);
```

After reading the user input

```
Car car = new Car();
car.setmake(make);
car.setmodel(model);
car.setcolor(color);
car.setmiles(miles);
car.setyear(year);

inventory.addCar(car);

String inventory = mapper.writeValueAsString(inventory);

System.out.println(inventory);
```

or you could just print the list from the inventory

```
String carList = mapper.writeValueAsString(inventory.getCarList());
```